# If I entered 100 small raffles with varying numbers of entries each but only 1 allowed per person, how likely am I to win?

Tags: probability

Our company is raffling off 100 different items for charity and plan to do so at least once a month. Each item is totally unique, so not all 100 will appeal to everyone. Most people will enter 10 or less, we're estimating. People are allowed to enter as many or as few different raffles as they want, but everyone can only have one raffle ticket per item.

SUPPOSING someone entered all 100 out of 100 raffles (each with total final # of entries ranging between 25 and 200 depending on popularity) and assuming EACH entry represents one 'contestant' how likely is that person to win one or more of these?

I've never been good at math, but we're having some small raffles and want to offer a guarantee that everyone will eventually win. Just need to estimate about how many entries into different raffles SHOULD result in a win.

(I guess if it helps, you could show me how to figure if 25 people enter and then if 200 did, or if it would be best to base it on an average.)

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Let me see if I get this: there are 100 games, each with (say) a 1 in 25 chance of winning the prize. We desire to find the probability of winning at least one game. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: Since you're looking for *everyone* to win at least one of the raffles, shouldn't you be calculating the chance of *that* happening?

Comment: Sean, yes. And Bram28 oh yikes! Should I?

Comment: Math deals with precise questions and can give precise answers to those (sometimes).  Are there the same number of people entering each raffle?  If not, what is the distribution?  Are you asking about each person having a good chance (whatever that is) of winning or having a good chance of every person winning (as in nobody has not won)?  Those are *very*different.  Please formulate a clear question.

Comment: Ah, I see where I was confusing. I hope it is more clear now. It's been edited.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if I understand correctly, you have $100$ independent raffles, for each of which everyone can decide separately whether to enter them. One person enters all $100$ of them, and you want to know the probability that that person wins at least one of them.

If $n$ people enter each raffle, then the probability of winning a particular one of them is $\frac1n$. The probability of winning none of them is then $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{100}$, so the probability of winning at least one of them is $1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{100}$. For large $n$ (where $n=25$ is already large enough), this can be approximated as $1-\exp\left(-\frac{100}n\right)$. Thus, for $n=25$ the probability of winning at least one is $1-\mathrm e^{-4}\approx0.982=98.2\%$, whereas for $n=100$ it's only $1-\mathrm e^{-1}\approx0.632=63.2\%$.